# OneToOne ConstraintViolation while saving a new Record, PK Provided

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

We have an Entity called `Customers` that has a OneToOne relationship to the Entity `Address`.

The `Customer`'s PK should be manually defined. The `Address`' PK should be automatically defined.

So, in `Customer` I omitted the `@GeneratedValue` and I'm providing is value manually. But, when trying to save I'm getting the following error:

```
2018-11-07 10:42:17.810 ERROR 1257 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Validation failed for classes [br.com.customers.entity.Address] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='não pode ser nulo', propertyPath=street, rootBeanClass=class br.com.customers.entity.Address, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
```

The problem is that the `address.street` is being provided and I can't realize why JPA is complaining that it's null...

Here are the JSON body that I'm trying to save. (It's being deserialized correctly, as, Address is not NULL)

```
{
    "customer_Id": 50,
    "name": "name",
    "company_name": "company_name",
    "email": "email@provider.com",
    "business_phone": "(00) 1111-2222",
    "mobile_phone": "(00) 1111-2222",
    "document": "123456789",
    "state_registration_number": "ISENTO",
    "state_registration_type": "NO_CONTRIBUTOR",
    "city_registration_number": "ISENTO",
    "classification": "AUTO",
    "address": {
        "street": "STREET NAME",
        "number": "NUMBER",
        "complement": "COMPLEMENT",
        "zip_code": "ZIP_CODE",
        "neighborhood": "NEIGHBORHOOD",
        "city": "CITY",
        "state": "STATE"
    }
}
```

Here are the Customer Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "X_CUSTOMERS")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private int customer_Id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private String company_name;

    private String email;

    private String business_phone;

    private String mobile_phone;

    @NotNull
    private String document;

    private String state_registration_number;

    private String state_registration_type;

    private String city_registration_number;

    @NotNull
    private String classification;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

}
```

And here, Address Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "X_ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int address_Id;

    @NotNull
    private String street;

    private String number;

    private String complement;

    private String zip_code;

    private String neighborhood;

    private String city;

    private String state;

}
```

What Am I doing wrong?
Thanks!!!

---

Adding the code do persist the entities:

Customer Repository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

}
```

To persist:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomersController {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public CustomersController(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }


}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `@JoinColumn(name = "address_Id")`?

Comment: I tried to change `@JoinColumn(name = "address_Id")`, but no success.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are persisting the entities?

Comment: Sure! I edited the answer to provide this information @AlainCruz

Answer (score 1):

From reading the Hibernate documentation, the save operation only persist entities with auto generated ids. So, if you intend to set the id yourself, then what you need, is to change your insert method for persist. And since you customer has an id that is not auto generated, maybe this could be the issue. You can read more in this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate).

```
@PostMapping
public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    return customerRepository.persist(customer);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If if remove the OneToOne relationship, the record is saved successfully. I think that the problem is related to the relationship itself...

Comment: Is there a way to make Address.address_Id follows the same key of Customer (customer.customer_id)? Eg, if I post a customer with Customer_id = 50, how to make Address.Address_id also assumes the value of '50'?

Comment: You mean, having a list of customers that belong to that address? Or that address_Id becomes the same of that of the customer?

Comment: The address_id becomes the same Id of the customer.

Comment: They only way would be to eliminated the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and manually set the id. So something like this `customer.setId(1); address.setId(customer.getId());`. Anyways, you are already setting the customer id yourself.

Comment: after changing the `cascade` atribute of `Customer.Address`' atribute from `Cascade.PERSIST`to `CASCADE.ALL`, now, the addresses is being generated correctly, but, when I try to edit the Customer, without passing the previous generated AddressID, a new Address is being generated. Is there a way to instruct Hibernate to update the previous address without passing its ID?

Comment: I believe you can solve it by using the `@DynamicUpdate` annotation ok your customer class. This will let Hibernate know, that you will modified only those fields that has been changed and will ignore nulls.

Comment: Unfortunately, @DynamicUpdate didn't change that behavior.

Comment: Hello, @Alain Cruz.you are right in hibernate session API. but save method of JPA data repository calls persist method of EntityManager(this.em.persist(entity))

Answer (score 0):

If you add CascadeType.MERGE, it will work

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;
```

you set the customer id(50) so the following line of SimpleJpaRepository will be executed.

```
return this.em.merge(entity);
```

Comment: Ok, but this way I need to manually do customer.getAddress().setCustomerId(customer.getCustomerId())? Isn’t it a little hacky?

Comment: you do not need it. by adding this cascade type you just need call save method of the repository. I thought your relationship is unidirectional(customer to address) so my test was unidirectional. it is natural that if you set id, hibernate will call the merge method.

Comment: I tried this approach here, but it didn't worked as expected. When I first POST the data, JPA creates two records: CustomerID with ID = 50 and Address with a ID = 1. If I post the same data again, the Customer is updated (because I have the CustomerID), but the address is duplicated with a new ID (in this case, 2). This is because the JSON that is being submitted don't have an 'address_id' on it.